# Php Encode - Java Decode (URL parts)

Tags: java, php, encoding, decoding

I have code where an url is decoded in php. Then parts from it are used to create a String containing Key-Value-Pairs (like Param=EncodedPartOfUrl&Param2=EncondedPartofUrl&...) with `(urlencode)`

Now I want to decode it in Java. Can I use the `URLDecoder` for it or might there be a incompatibility? I also guess that in PHP there is no encoding scheme specified (when I understand the docs correctly) - how do I solve this then in java? Don't use a specified econding scheme (which is deprecated in Java 6 for `URLDecoder`)?

Comment: Are you doing this in a servlet or a jsp?

Comment: on the java side? none of both, I "receive" it as "data"

Comment: So this is not a java web application you're working with? A java SE(desktop) application then?

Comment: no, it is not a webapplication. Its simply a java program working with data and generating more data as output. ;-)

Comment: in that case please provide some code of how you're trying to do this so that someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I think the code I showed should be enough information. My question is more a general question than a code specific question, I think.

Comment: Since there's more than one way to do what you want code would have been helpful in providing you with a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't You just build Your URL, then `url_encode` it in PHP and then use Your URLDecoder in Java (or whatever it is)?

URL encoding just of values from Key-Value pairs is not enough and not quite good approach - You should URL encode the whole URL for this...

**EDIT**:

> Thanks for your answer, but I have no influence there. I can only work on the java side of code.

Then You have the only possibility: parse the URL to get the `GET` parameters and URL decode each of their values separately...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have no influence there. I can only work on the java side of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. thats what I thought. I parse the Parameters and then I decode. The question is, are there incompatibilities? What about the encodign scheme?

Comment: @nano7 If they use `url_encode()` on PHP side there should be no incompatibility as it preserves HTTP standards.

Comment: They use urlencode(), but I thought this creates platform specific results. In Java I can decide wether I use a specific encoding scheme or not. If I use an encoding scheme, maybe I would create wrong decoded results ? Not using an encoding scheme means using a deprecated method,,,

Comment: Then I am sorry cos I do not see into the Java UrlDecoder and cannot ell You whether there will be incompatibilities or not... You can only try and You'll see...